# Problema com Font Face

Tags: html, wordpress, font

Estou usando Font face no WORDPRESS, e na hospedagem local (WAMP) ele pega a font, porem quando publico online ele não pega a font que quero.

a pasta da font está em:
ONLINE: public_html/wp-content\themes\eddiemachado-bones-cfbfb62\library\fonts
LOCAL: localhost/ecg/wp-content\themes\eddiemachado-bones-cfbfb62\library\fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aileron-SemiBoldItalic';
    src: url('../fonts/Aileron-SemiBoldItalic.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Aileron-SemiBoldItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Aileron-SemiBoldItalic.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Aileron-SemiBoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Aileron-SemiBoldItalic.svg#Aileron-SemiBoldItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: provavelmente o problema é com o caminho relativo, e não com a fonte. `('../fon`. Experimente por o caminho desde a raiz: `/recursos/fontes/nomedafonte.ttf` (adapte o caminho para o seu caso específico)

Comment: Um problema básico é configurar a hospedagem local em nível diferente do remoto, e a pasta "ecg" indica que você fez exatamente isso. Melhor seria hospedar na raiz do localhost (e se for testar sites diferentes, criar entradas para cada um deles no HOSTS do pc).

Comment: Se o problema não for no caminho, certifique se de duas coisas: uma óbvia, é ver se as fontes estão publicadas. Outra nem tanto, é verificar se o servidor web está com os mime-types de cada uma das extensões configurado corretamente. No meu servidor eu precisei cadastrar manualmente boa parte dos formatos.

Comment: amigos, era um problema na hospedagem já resolvi ligando para lá :D